# AJAX - Displaying current status of the connection to users

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I will need to pull data from many datasources - this is a time-consuming process. 
If user sends the form the program pulls data from 7 tables ( using ajax )

I would like to provide an information what is actually going on ,for example "Pulling data from table1" , "Pulling data from table2" and so on.

but have no idea how to do this - Is there a good standard for this kind of task ?
I am using python/django as a backend

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrap each of the 7 calls into their own functions and do a promise chain. Make part of each of your chains set a status variable that's then displayed to the user. [Intro to promises...](https://html5hive.org/how-to-chain-javascript-promises/)

Comment: thanks @Ryan C. I am aware of promises but in that case i would need to run 7 separate connections . In case of many users that may cause the problems right ?

Comment: @JsTest Well you would only be running one connection at a time. So at the end of your chain, yes, there would have been 7 calls made. But during the chain, you would only have one connection active at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [XHR onprogress function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress) to stream data in JavaScript. The function gets called periodically whenever data is flushed from the server. So use `sys.stdout.flush()` in Python to force a flush whenever you want to display the current status.

---

**test.py**

```
import sys
import time

for x in range(5):
    print(x)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**test.html**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Begin Stream</button>
<div id="app"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#btn").on("click", () => {

            $.ajax('test.py', {
                xhrFields: {
                    onprogress: (e) => {
                        $("#app").html(e.currentTarget.response);
                    }
                }
            })
            .done((data) => {
                $("#app").html(`DONE: ${data}`);
            })
            .fail((data) => {
                $("#app").html(`ERROR: ${data}`);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```